# Initialise a common static vector accessible to all derived class objects

Tags: c++

I have two classes, a `base` class:

```
class base {
    protected:
        static vector <int> myVec; // creates static vector
    public:
        base(int x) { // initialises the vector with size x
            myVec.resize(x);
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { // assigns integer 0 to each vector index position
                myVec[i] = 0;
                }
        }
};
```

and a `derived` class:

```
class derived : public base {
    public:
        derived(int x) : base {x} {}

        void editVec(int pos) {
            myVec[pos] = 1; // assign integer 1 to index position pos
        }
        void printVec() { // iterates through the vector printing each value to the cmd line
            for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++){
                cout << myVec[i] << " ";
            } cout << endl;
        }
};
```

I would like to create two objects of the `derived` class and allow both objects to access and modify the same static vector attribute `myVec`.

When i create the two `derived` objects, they each create their own `myVec` attribute, rather than sharing a common static attribute. Is it possible to ensure both objects share the same `myVec` attribute?

```
int main() {
    derived obj1(5); // create instance of derived
    obj1.editVec(0); // modify myVec attribute, assign integer 1 to index position 0
    obj1.printVec(); // outputs 1 0 0 0 0
    
    derived obj2(5); // create second instance of Class
    obj2.printVec(); // outputs 0 0 0 0 0, not 1 0 0 0 0
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally would like the `obj2.printVec()` method call to output '1 0 0 0 0'.

Comment: What do you think the constructor for `base` does for the second object created after the vector has been modified?

Comment: Ideally, a static attribute should not depend on each object of that class.

Comment: I believe the object is creating its own vector attribute, ideally I would like the second object to access the same attribute created by the first object. @RetiredNinja

Comment: @MazdaMan No, you're not creating the vector each time you create a new object. You're just resizing and then resetting the vector in the constructor. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: try `obj1.printVec();` as last line in `main` to see that there is only 1 vector used by the two instances

Comment: Do things in a different order and see a different picture. https://godbolt.org/z/ah4Mh1vY5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe the object is creating its own vector attribute

No, you're not creating `myVec` each time you create the class' instance. Instead the **problem** is that when you create the second object using `derived obj2(5)`, the base class ctor resizes the vector and then sets/assigns each `myVec`'s element to `0`.

Basically, you're **resizing and then resetting `myVec` with each object.**

---

I would also recommend using a debugger: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)